# How to use matplotlib kwargs for custom formatting across functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, data-science

I'm editing a function to create date plots and it has formatting parameters hardcoded. I'm trying to add a `format_ax` type function for the sake of brevity and flexibility. I've read the documentation on [custom styling](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) in matplotlib,  but I'm confused about how or if you can encapsulate all desired axis.set_xxx() arguments into one function you could easily manipulate and call across multiple customized plotting-functions. Primarily, I want to know: **Can I/How do I pass kwargs for ax.set?**

The function I've written already has kwargs for formatting the desired colors. I tried pulling out the relevant lines of code into it's own function. For example:

```
def format_ax_nicely(ax, **kwargs):
       ax.set_ylim(bottom=ymin, top=ymax)
```

But when I called `format_ax_nicely` in `my_timeseries_function` as following: `format_ax_nicely(ax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)` I got an error `NameError: name 'ymin' is not defined`.

Using `ax.set()` is another approach I considered, but you can't set sizes, only define limits and values, etc..

I also tried the function definition method [defined here](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/) with `def add_titlebox` but I still wasn't able to use kwargs. I got this error:

```
     File "C:\Users\ceres\code\improc\analysis\plot.py", line 390, in my_timeseries
       title(ax, title, size=20)

  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**edit: thank you to @TheImportanceOfBeingErnest for pointing out why these errors occurred!

This is the approximate structure of my function:

```
def my_timeseries_function(lots of parameters, **kwargs, **plotargs):
     # set up filesaving destination
     # cleanup dataframe
     # set labels
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
     hues = create_custom_color_values(df, cmap, **kwargs)
     ax.grid(color="k", linestyle="-", linewidth=0.05)
     for g in labels:
          # plot x,y with custom colors
     # roughly 15 lines of formatting functions like set_ylabel, ax.legend, 
     # xaxis.set_major_locator, tick_params, conditional set_ylim which 
     # would ideally be replaced by:
     format_ax_nicely(ax, **plotargs)
```

The aim of this question is how to achieve a "format" function `my_timeseries` can call. However, as I'm a novice, if that's not recommended by users of matplotlib, then I'm secondarily asking *if a style sheet is "better"?* It seems hard to tweak, as the style sheet is part of the global environment, but it also could be a possible answer to my objective: more easily style my plots.

**Additional background**
Some Seaborn packages achieve flexibility by keeping all the formatting within the function. I cannot use their package because I need to color the points in a way they can't currently achieve, and I also cannot create a seaborn dependency in the package I'm working in.

Relevant packages to my class:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cm as cm
try:
    import geoplot
except BaseException:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem understanding what exactly you need here. I do think the approach to use a function, which styles the axes is not too bad.

Maybe a reminder: If a variable is not defined it cannot be used. Hence the error you get.
Options you have are

- *Define the argument*

  ```
  def format_ax_nicely(ax, ymin=0, ymax=1):
      ax.set_ylim(bottom=ymin, top=ymax)
  ```
- *Get argument from keywords*

  ```
  def format_ax_nicely(ax, **kwargs):
      ax.set_ylim(bottom=kwargs.get("ymin", 0), top=kwargs.get("ymax", 1))
  ```
- Concerning fontsize of the title, that would be

  ```
  ax.title.set_size(20)
  ```

---

Some *style* options can be set globally via [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html). They include fonts, sizes, colors, axes ticks appearance etc. However limits of the plot are not part of those. You can use them in a context for temporary styling though

```
with plt.style.context(('my_style_sheet')):
    my_timeseries_function(lots of parameters, kwargs, plotargs)
plt.show()
```